# RAID1 configuration

Tags: hard-drive, server-security

I have server PowerEdge R640 which has 2 Bay SSD and 6 SAS the server now on production and runining,but there is no any type of RAID configured only one hard disk holds the data as drive C but reciently the whole free space became ciritical and we want to replace it with biger hard disk and configure RAID 1 ,
the question how can I  build the two new hard disk (SSD)as RAID1 and clone the old hard disk whiout loosing and data.

Thank you ,

Comment: Perhaps https://serverfault.com/ is better suited.